# How to code the 2 lines, 4 buttons and white background in this Email only using HTML

Tags: css, html, frontend, user-experience

Today I tried to practice, and use HTML to code a simple email design. But until now I have a few questions not clearly, please see the image sample, so may I ask some help:

[image]

1. The middle white background. How to code this part use HTML?
2. The two pink lines, I tried use `<hr>` for this, but I don't know why the color won't change and the middle space which from first line to image top is not correct, so is there any other way to code the line?
3. The 4 buttons, how to HTML the 4 buttons?  The image sample button pink background looks like use as a shape?

I know these can used CSS to reach the effect but currently want all things ONLY done in HTML, is this possible based on this sample?

Please let me know if any guy who know how to solve these problems.

Comment: You'll have to use inline css in the html elements. CSS is how you style and position HTML, they go hand in hand. You have to use both to achieve the design you want.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Just to let you know, the `<style>` tag is also supported in emails. He can place all the CSS there.

Comment: @OmriLuzon Good to know, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed a lot of spelling mistakes. (See [ask] for formatting help, so that you can create the best question). Use backticks (\`) for your <hr> block so that it doesn't show an actual horizontal rule. Also: Reduce the noise down! We don't care that you're new, and you can skip salutations/thanks. We want questions, and we provide answers. Anything beyond that is clutter.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="lines"></div>
    <div class="title">MEMORIAL DAY</div>
    <div class="title2">SALE</div>
    <div class="lines"></div>
    <div class="text1">stock up blah blah</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sm-col margin">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">but1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">but2</button>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="sm-col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">but1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">but2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You need css to do the margins by the way. Really recommend Using it.
CSS:

```
.mainDiv {
  background-color: white;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.lines {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.title2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.text1{
  font-size:17;
}
.margin{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

[LINK TO JSFIDDLE :)))](https://jsfiddle.net/kumxjcqa/2/)